# How can I make Link Features for Link Prediction in Graph Convolutional Network or Logisitic Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, graph-neural-network

Currently studying Graph Convolutional Network or Logistic Regression and have come to understand how it works and how I can do node classifications with given node features but I have a difficulty in understand how to make link features for Link Prediciton using Graph Convolutional Network or Logistic Regression. Hope to hear some explanations.

Comment: The features can be arbitrary—please clarify what _about_ designing features is confusing you?

Comment: I want to do Link(Edge) Prediction using GCN or Logistic Regression but I am clear with how to make the edge features for the inpute and the target feature for the output. I just want to understand what the edge feature for the input and the target feature for the output look like